# Can I customize geddy scaffold templates?

Tags: node.js, geddy

Are geddy scaffold templates customizable? i.e Can I override standard view templates to add things on my own or change the way cruds are displayed?

Answer (score 1):

We have an issue going for this feature request here: https://github.com/mde/geddy/issues/526